# Python Selenium XPath not working as expected

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using selenium for python to crawl websites. But Xpath is not working as expected

```
<div>
    <div class="scrollableParent">
       <div class="test"></div> # this div is inserted after the first xpath event
    </div>
</div>

driver.find_elment_by_id('button_to_insert_test_div').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='test']")
```

For the second command I am getting an empty list, which is very strange. But the "funniest" thing is that those lines will give me the correct result:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'test')]")
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("test")
```

It seems that XPath without contains function doesn't re-rendering the page DOM?

edit: The test container is placed within a scrollable one. Maybe this is the reason why it cannot be fully parsed? But why it work with the two other commands?

Comment: no that's not ideal behavior, are you sure there's no trailing spaces in `test` class ?

Comment: Is the behaviour different than when you use xpath selector in browser dev tools?

Comment: Have you tried using the full xpath?

Comment: no trailing spaces, but the test container is scrollable, maybe that breaks it? @Samuel what do you mean with full xpath? It works in chrome dev tools xpath. So it must be a problem with selenium

Comment: We need to see the HTML first before saying it's a problem with Selenium, please share page url

Comment: @prodev116 right click the page and press inspect. Locate the element you want selenium to navigate to. Right click the element and chose “full xpath” instead of “xpath,” it might work, might not, try it!